# Certs from Smart Card not showing up or viewable in keychain

Tags: keychain, smart-card

I am trying to get a smart card reader functioning on my Mac just upgraded to 12.1 and the reader is seen by the system, and the card is shown, but no certs? Can put the card in a computer next to it (running windows and different reader) - works fine, bought a second reader same symptoms as the first on the Mac. I cannot view the card in KeyChain, and the commands I am executing don't seem to see the certs on the card. (Can validate  I am going to include as much detail as I can; hopefully, it's just a misconfiguration:

(PIV card works (tested it on a different system), unsure of the reader as it's brand new (bought it a while back, but put it in the box and never used it).

```
➜  Downloads ./cert_read.py
Running: 'system_profiler SPSmartCardsDataType' and parsing output...
There were NO certificates found. Is your badge inserted?
Here's all we saw in output (should be more than 100 lines) :
SmartCards:

    Readers:

      #01: Alcor Micro AU9520 (ATR:{length = 17, bytes = 0x3bd6970081b1fe451f878031c152411a2b})

    Reader Drivers:

      #01: org.debian.alioth.pcsclite.smartcardccid:1.4.32 (/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle)

    Tokend Drivers:

      #01: com.thursby.tokend.pkard:1.7 (/Library/Security/PKard/10.6/PKard.tokend)

    SmartCard Drivers:

      #01: com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.pivtoken:1.0(disabled) (/System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/PlugIns/pivtoken.appex)

    Available SmartCards (keychain):

        com.apple.setoken:

        com.apple.setoken:aks:

    Available SmartCards (token):

        com.apple.setoken:

        com.apple.setoken:aks:

Computer:
macOS Mojave 10.15.7
USB - C

Card reader:
GSR205 - USB C IOGEAR
(I checked the manufacturer's website, and there are no drivers available for download) 

The card reader shows up as the following in the PKard assistant: EMV Smart cardreader.
```

The second card reader shows up as follows:

```
➜  Downloads ./cert_read.py
Running: 'system_profiler SPSmartCardsDataType' and parsing output...
There were NO certificates found. Is your badge inserted?
Here's all we saw in output (should be more than 100 lines) :
SmartCards:

    Readers:

      #01: SCR3310 Smart Card Reader (ATR:{length = 17, bytes = 0x3bd6970081b1fe451f878031c152411a2b})

    Reader Drivers:

      #01: fr.apdu.ccid.smartcardccid:1.4.34 (/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle)
      #02: com.scmmicro.drivers.scmccid:(null) (/usr/local/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/scmccid.bundle)

    SmartCard Drivers:

      #01: com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.pivtoken:1.0(disabled) (/System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/PlugIns/pivtoken.appex)

    Available SmartCards (keychain):

        com.apple.setoken:

        com.apple.setoken:aks:

    Available SmartCards (token):

        com.apple.setoken:

        com.apple.setoken:aks:
```

also here is PCTEST:

```
Enter the reader number          : 01
Waiting for card insertion         
                                 : Command successful.
Testing SCardConnect             : Command successful.
Testing SCardStatus              : Command successful.
Current Reader Name              : SCR3310 Smart Card Reader
Current Reader State             : 0x54
Current Reader Protocol          : 0x1
Current Reader ATR Size          : 17 (0x11)
Current Reader ATR Value         : 3B D6 97 00 81 B1 FE 45 1F 87 80 31 C1 52 41 1A 2B 
Testing SCardDisconnect          : Command successful.
Testing SCardReleaseContext      : Command successful.
Testing SCardEstablishContext    : Command successful.
Testing SCardGetStatusChange 
Please insert a working reader   : Command successful.
Testing SCardListReaders         : Command successful.
Reader 01: SCR3310 Smart Card Reader
```

I have tried to insert/reinsert the card, connect and reconnect the reader, and tried different ports with a few reboots to add to see if anything would change..no dice. Also upgraded from Catalina to Montrey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keychain access uses `tokend`. `Tokend` has been dead since 10.15, and trying to find certs there in any way will not happen.

I ran the following command to validate what had been disabled:

```
security smartcards token -l "com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.pivtoken"
```

Most likely, the Thursby TokenD disabled it.

```
#01: com.thursby.tokend.pkard:1.7 (/Library/Security/PKard/10.6/PKard.tokend)
```

Remove that from your system, and you should be good to go after running that command to enable

```
security smartcard token -e com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.pivtoken
```

Removing the old driver from Thursby did the trick; I used the uninstaller from Thursby.

As a minor note, I believe the driver came from Mac to Mac transfer that I did from an old computer that I had forgotten.